# Unable to create db when registering user using asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, database-connection, asp.net-identity

Here is my connection string. I am using SQL Server Express 2016.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UsersDB;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Getting the following error when trying to register user.

```
ExceptionMessage: "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."
ExceptionType:"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
Message:"An error has occurred."
```

And if i create a db "UsersDB" then getting the below error in picture.

[image]

There is no error when adding `User Instance=True` to the connection string but unable to find "UsersDB" in management studio or server explorer.

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory, what more do you want to know?!

Comment: Why its not creating UsersDB?

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine as i added userid, password and removed "Integrated Security"

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UsersDB;User ID=****;Password=****;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```